# Is it grammatically correct to invert the position of a noun and its adjunct, such as using "size dress" to mean "dress size"?

Tags: grammar

I have noticed what appears to be a growing trend to invert the position of the words in phrases like "lens shape" and "ring width", turning them into ["shape lens"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/621225/what-shape-lens-will-focus-parallel-laser-beams-to-the-smallest-point) and ["width ring"](https://www.flinnandsteel.co.uk/blogs/making-of-a-sheffield-steel-ring/what-width-ring-should-i-choose) respectively.

The same thing can be observed in the title of the [NPR article](https://www.npr.org/2022/02/09/1078977416/race-chat-emoji-skin-tone-colors) *Which skin color emoji should you use? The answer can be more complex than you think*, wherein the phrase "skin color emoji" is used to refer to the colour of the emoji.

Is this a grammatically correct practice?

Comment: @peanutjelly: I think you may be a bit confused. It's not OK to say "shape lens" with the meaning of "lens shape". But you _can_ ask "What shape lens do you have?" (More formally this might be rendered as "What shape of lens ... ?"). In a normal sentence the adjective of shape comes before the noun (round lens, square lens, ...), and this form of question is simply parallel with that.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's not 100% clear, but I'm assuming the question is about the article title saying "skin color emoji" when it's referring to the choice of which "emoji skin colour" to use.

Comment: You can say "this is the wrong size dress", but this means something different to "this is the wrong dress size": the former is talking about the dress, the latter refers to the size. "Wrong size" acts as a modifier for dress in "wrong size dress". I don't know the formal terms for this.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed. It's about the English language and its usage. I think there's a lot to talk about here.

Comment: @DjinTonic et al, I'm also puzzled about the close reason. It does look like the problem the OP perceives is based on a misperception about mechanics, but it's a complex enough one that it bears explication IMO.

Comment: The "shape lens" example is not an inversion of "lens shape". The question is "What shape lens is..." and is just an abbreviation of "What shape *of* lens is...". "shape lens" is not a noun phrase there.

Comment: @psmears Why is it incorrect to say "lens shape" in the example I gave and the one you gave? Are the phrases "dress size" and "ring width", by the same token, incorrect?

Comment: When we say "An ocarina is a small ceramic musical instrument with a _lens shape_" we are using 'shape' as a noun and 'lens' as a modifier of 'shape'. In other words we are saying that the shape of an ocarina is similar to that of a round biconvex optical lens. However if we say "What shape lens do you require?" we are using _lens_ as a noun and  _shape_ as a modifier. For instance the person requiring the lens might want a round one which is biconvex, biconcave, plano-convex or even one which is octagonal. The order of the words changes which one is the noun and which the modifier.

Comment: @peanutjelly: I didn't say it would necessarily be incorrect to say "lens shape"; I said that (a) "... shape lens" _is_ correct (in the right context), and (b) "... shape lens" isn't simply an inverted version of "lens shape". If someone asks "What shape lens do you have?", they're not asking you to identify the type of "\*shape lens" you have; they're asking, regarding the "lens" that you have, to tell them "what shape" it is. Does that clarify? (BTW are you a native speaker?)

Comment: @psmears Sorry, but I am not clear at all as to what the difference is between "lens shape" and "shape lens". What is the difference between 'type of "shape lens"' and 'shape of lens'?

Comment: @StuartF How is the "this is the wrong size dress" talking about of dress? Is "size dress" a type of dress?

Comment: @peanutjelly: The difference is that "shape lens" just isn't a phrase you can use. (The "\*" is a convention for marking usage not considered "correct"). Just because two words happen to come next to each other in one sentence doesn't mean they're "joined" as a phrase that you can use in any context. So for example you can ask "Are dogs animals?", but "dogs animals" isn't a phrase on its own; you can't say "\*I like dogs animals". The same is happening with "shape lens": you can ask "What shape lens" but that's "(What shape) (lens)", just like "(square) (lens)", **not** "\*(what) (shape lens)"

Comment: @peanutjelly: "red dress" refers to a dress (a red one); so does "big dress" (a big one). "Wrong size dress" is the same - it is a dress that is the wrong size. "Wrong dress size" is different - that's a size (of dress) that isn't the right one.

Comment: @psmears Whenever someone talks about "shape lens", they are invariably talking about the shape of a lens, which is more correctly worded as either "lens shape" or "shape of lens". If a seller sends you a size 6 dress instead of a size 8 one, then they sent you the "wrong (dress) size" as the seller **did get the size to be sent wrong**; if you pick a dress in a shop and try to put it on, only to find that it won't fit or is too loose, you'd say that it is a "wrong size dress", which is not really correct as, unless the dress is defective, the size of the dress is not itself wrong.

Comment: @psmears It would be more accurate, more precise and fairer to describe it as a (much-)(too-)tight or (much-)(too-)loose dress. The distinction between "wrong size dress", relating to how the dress fits the wearer, and "wrong dress size", relating to how it compares to other dresses, is artificial, misleading and unnecessary. Similarly, saying that a person has used "a wrong skin colour emoji" can be interpreted as the person having used an emoji of a colour which is proscribed or questionable — that is, which is inherently-wrong —, which is clearly not what is actually meant.

Comment: @peanutjelly: Are you a native speaker?

Comment: @psmears No. Why?